# socket.io Undo/Redo Stack with Multiple Users

Tags: node.js, socket.io, codemirror

I have socket.io with node.js working really well with the CodeMirror editor to synchronize code across multiple users. However, the undo/redo stack is associated with all edits regardless of the user. How do I make it so each user has their own undo/redo stack rather than undoing/redoing other users' edits? Here is my server code:

```
var package = require("../../package.json");

// packages
var express = require("express");
var fs = require("fs");

// express (web server and http server)
var app = express();
var server = require("https").Server(options, app).listen(3100);
var io = require("socket.io")(server, { pingTimeout: 4000, pingInterval: 2000 });

// starts the array of sockets
var clients = [];

// checks if a connection is made
io.sockets.on("connection", function (socket) {

    // gets the file ID
    var ciphertext = socket.handshake.query["ciphertext"];

    // adds the socket to the socket array
    socket.ciphertext = ciphertext;
    socket.username = socket.handshake.query["username"];
    socket.user = socket.handshake.query["user"];

    // adds the socket to the list of clients
    clients.push(socket);

    // checks if the change code has been sent
    socket.on("change", function(op) {

        // sees if the user has typed, pasted, cut, or deleted text or if the editor has autocompleted
        if (op.origin == "+input" || op.origin == "paste" || op.origin == "cut" || op.origin == "+delete" || op.origin == "+insert" || op.origin == "complete" || op.origin == "undo" || op.origin == "redo" ) {

            // loops through all sockets and pushes the changes if not the current socket and the same page
            clients.forEach(function (client) {
                if (client != socket && client.ciphertext == ciphertext) client.emit("change", op);
            });
        };
    });

    // checks if the socket disconnected and clears the highlighted text for the socket
    socket.on("disconnect", function(){
        var existingClients = [];
        var i = clients.indexOf(socket);
        clients.splice(i, 1);
        clients.forEach( function (client) {
            existingClients.push(client.username);
        });
        clients.forEach( function (client) {
            client.emit("end", existingClients);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Currently you are just emitting the changes received from the editor which stores only one state of the document being edited by multiple users. You will have to store the user operations `socket.undoOps = []` and `socket.redoOps=[]`. Create an object for every action that helps achieve the state and also the reverse and push it to the undoOps array.

Comment: @MukulDev Great! Thank you. So if I understand correctly, something like this: `if (op.origin != "undo") { socket.undoOps.push(op); } else if (op.origin == "undo") { socket.redoOps.push(op); }` However, how do I get it so that the browser doesn't undo changes that have been emitted by other users?

Comment: It should be `if (op.origin == "undo") {
    let lastUndo = socket.undoOps.pop();
    socket.redoOps.push(lastUndo);
}
else if (op.origin == "redo") {
    socket.redoOps.pop();
}
else {
    //any action other than undo or redo
    socket.undoOps.push(op);
    // continue with your current code

}`. You will have to override the implementation of undo and redo from the client side (Editor) that prevents the editor from making changes by itself and instead make changes based on the event received from the server.